# OnRowCommand in the Gridview gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to use the `GridViewCommandEventArgs` in the grid view but when I run it keeps saying:Updating is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless UpdateCommand is specified.

I have multiple `Linkbuttons` in the Grid hence the `OnRowCommand`

OnRowCommand ="Grid_Row"

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Update" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Serno") %>' runat="server"    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Update this?');" CommandName ="Update" >Update</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField> 
             <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="Remove" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Serno") %>' runat="server"    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Remove this Item?');" CommandName ="Remove" >Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField> 




   protected void Grid_Row(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{



    LinkButton Remove = (LinkButton)GridView1.FindControl("Remove");
    LinkButton Update = (LinkButton)GridView1.FindControl("Update");
    if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
    {
        try
        {

            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constring);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" update [Order_Items] set status=0 WHERE [Serno] =" + index.ToString() + "", con);
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {


                GridView1.DataBind();
                msg_lbl.Text = "Record Deleted";

            }
            else
            {

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {


        }
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        try
        {


            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

           [Convert.ToDouble(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("Quantity");

            GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            string Q = ((TextBox)clickedRow.FindControl("Quantity_Txt") as TextBox).Text;
            string P = ((Label )clickedRow.FindControl("Amount_Lbl") as Label ).Text;


            double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(Q);

            double Price = Convert.ToDouble(P);
            double Calc = Quantity * Price;


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constring);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update [Order_Items] set Quantity='"+Quantity +"', Money='" + Calc + "' WHERE [Serno] =" + index.ToString() + "", con);
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {


                GridView1.DataBind();
                msg_lbl.Text = "Record Updated";



            }
            else
            {

            }
            con.Close();
            }

        catch
        {


        }

    }



}
```

Comment: What was your sql query and the `SelectCommand`, Can you post the code you used???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because you specify keyword for you command name.change them to other words like : `UPD` or `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't specified the UpdateCommand in your data source.

The same way as you specify the select command and select parameters, you have to specify the update command.

Hope this helps

Comment: You can also try to change the commandName to something different than 'Update' or 'Remove'. These might be some keywords. Try setting it to e.g. 'Update1' and see if it works.